# How to keep unit tests and production code in sync?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, rider

We often have difficulty finding unit tests for a given production code class, even with conventions such as having the tests assembly name be the production code assembly name + ".Tests" and consistent namespaces and folders within the tests assembly.

The issue arises when classes are renamed or moved due to refactoring. Is there a solution to automatically enforce these conventions or is there a better way to make unit tests for a given code class more discoverable?

Sure we can use the "find references" feature in the IDE, but we often only load the assemblies that contain the code we are currently working on to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to write tests for the tests  the Roslyn APIs make it pretty straightforward to analyze the structure of a C# file. So a test could look like this:

1. Load the whole solution with Roslyn.
2. Iterate over all classes not ending on `Fixture`, `Test`, etc. (whatever your test suffix is).
3. For each element of #2, check whether there is a corresponding element with the suffix (the test class).

##### My personal opinion

But depending on the size and structure of the code, I'd consider this an anti-pattern. Why? Because if we didn't distinguish between *test code* and *production code*, we would say something like this: *Hmmm, whenever I have to change class A, I have to change class B as well*.
And this is high coupling, something we typically want to avoid (although there might be exceptions).

Imho *test code* is a first-class citizen of a codebase and therefore, there is no distinction between *test code* and *production code* - there is only *code*. And code needs a particular architecture to keep it maintainable, i. e. decoupling, etc.

Therefore I'd vote for naming test classes according to feature, not classes, and test methods for behavior rather than class methods.

If you're interested in this topic, I can recommend [Dennis Doomen's blog *The Continous Improver*](https://www.continuousimprover.com) and especially the following two articles:

- [What’s the “unit” in unit testing and why is it not a class](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2023/04/unit-testing-scope.html)
- [My Laws of Test Driven Development](https://www.continuousimprover.com/2021/10/laws-test-driven-development.html)

Comment: Also for a large solution it would be very slow to iterate every production code class. Maybe the other way around, iterate all tests and check if they matches to production code per convention. Because even when having high test coverage one always has much more classes then tests since lots of things you often do not want to test (viewmodels, controls, DTOs)

Comment: I find the idea, that a "unit" is not necessarily a class very interesting, but imho this makes my problem worse, right? Also it makes it even harder to see which parts of the code are already under test (without coverage tool support). Also I image it can be harder to understand a test, when it is not clear what is the "sut" when more than one class is tested?

Comment: For your particular question, I totally agree - it just broke my developer heart to provide an answer for a pattern that I don't agree with  that's why I felt obliged to put it into context.